# How do I add a customer logged in menu to a page from the local.xml file

Tags: blocks, customer, static-block, header

I am working on getting a menu appearing in a magento template in the header.phtml file.

In my local.xml file I have the following code:

```
<!-- ################### LOGGED IN ################### -->

      <customer_logged_in>

         <!-- Account Menu -->
        <reference name="my_account_menu">
            <!-- <remove name="mini_login" /> -->
            <block type="core/template" name="my_account_menu_block" template="page/html/menu/account_logged_in.phtml" />
        </reference>

      </customer_logged_in>

      <!-- ################### LOGGED OUT ################### -->

      <customer_logged_out>

        <!-- Account Menu -->
        <reference name="my_account_menu">
          <!-- <block type="customer/form_login" name="mini_login" template="page/html/menu/mini.login.phtml" /> -->
          <block type="customer/form_login" name="my_account_menu_block" template="page/html/menu/account_logged_out.phtml" />
        </reference>

      </customer_logged_out>
```

What I want to do is add this into my header template and switch for each logged in/logged out state.

Currently I am doing this in the header:

```
<? if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() || (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestString() == "/customer/cart")) { ?>
    <?= $this->getChildHtml('loggedin_menu') ?>
    <h3>logged in</h3>
<? } else { ?>
    <?= $this->getChildHtml('my_account_menu_block') ?>
    <h3>logged out</h3>
<? } ?>
```

This works for the logged in menu but not for the logged out menu.

Does anyone have an idea of a cleaner approach to this?

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display one block or the other via mutually exclusive layout update handles, you do not need a conditional in your template. Rather, just unconditionally a child via a given alias/name, and use layout handles to conditionally determine which block type & template are used.

**Template example (snip of from *`page/html/header.phtml`*):**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customerStateContent') ?>
```

**Layout XML example:**

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <!-- Account Menu -->
    <block type="core/template"
           name="customerStateContent"
           parent="header"
           template="page/html/menu/account_logged_in.phtml" />
</customer_logged_in>

<customer_logged_in>
    <!-- Account Login Form -->
    <block type="customer/form_login"
           name="customerStateContent"
           parent="header"
           template="page/html/menu/account_logged_out.phtml" />
</customer_logged_in>
```

That's the simple example. Again, the customer module adds one handle or the other, so you should make use of that.

If you need to have a common wrapper template for each of these (`my_account_menu` in your snippet would indicate this) then you can simply do the following:

**Template example (snip of from *`page/html/header.phtml`*):**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customerStateContent') ?>
```

**Template example (snip of from `customerStateContent` template):**

```
<div class="whatever-markup-to-justify-using-a-template">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('stateSpecificContent') ?>
    <!-- could also just use $this->getChildHtml() if no other children are assigned -->
</div>
```

**Layout XML example:**

```
<default>
    <block type="core/template" name="customerStateContent" parent="header" template="[...]"  />
</default>

<customer_logged_in>
    <!-- Account Menu -->
    <block type="core/template"
           name="stateSpecificContent"
           parent="customerStateContent
           template="page/html/menu/account_logged_in.phtml" />
</customer_logged_in>

<customer_logged_in>
    <!-- Account Login Form -->
    <block type="customer/form_login"
           name="customerStateContent"
           parent="customerStateContent"
           template="page/html/menu/account_logged_out.phtml" />
</customer_logged_in>
```

In the latter example, a generic containing block for your state-specific content is added for all views via the `<default />` handle, and you are conditionally adding one child or another to it. Note that it's slightly against convention to give two different blocks the same `name`, but it would not matter in this case.

Comment: Spot on, thanks very much. It was the simpler approach that worked, I think in my local.xml file the reference="something" was throwing Magento off a little so it could not find it. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: It's an either/or with references. Either skip them altogether and use parent, or use the parent value for the reference name value.

Comment: Do you know if this is similar to the way of showing the templates on certain pages. Can I do this in local.xml? What I mean is can I show this in certain pages too?

Comment: Each page has a unique layout update handle. See [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::addActionLayoutHandles()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L289). Note that layouts directives in the DB (either a page layout or custom layout XML) execute after file-based layout directives. This means that a CMS page or a product page can have entity-level layout settings which supersede *`local.xml`*.

Comment: So in short adding this template to an account page only will require a layout.xml file that creates a new block and adds the template that way?

Comment: There is the `<customer_account>` handle which is invoked for all customer account pages. You could at the containing parent in `<customer_account>`, then assign each child using `<customer_logged_in/out>` handles.